# Zap API: endpoints unavailable

Tags: zap

I am running Zap version 2.10.0 and was hoping to gain more control of logins with users.authenticate_as_user, [link](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/blob/master/src/zapv2/users.py#L102)

It is, however, unavailable as when I list attributes of a `users` object in python I only get (besides dunder methods):

```
'get_authentication_credentials', 'get_authentication_credentials_config_params', 'get_user_by_id', 'new_user', 'remove_user',
'set_authentication_credentials', 'set_user_enabled', 'set_user_name', 'users_list', 'zap'.
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Which version of the ZAP python API do you have installed?
The latest version is 0.0.18: https://pypi.org/project/python-owasp-zap-v2.4/

Comment: @Simon Bennetts Using a docker image: FROM owasp/zap2docker-stable:2.10.0. When I run pip install python-owasp-zap-v2.4 I get: Requirement already satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making assumptions about how the API and API client work that are wrong.

Your best bet is to look at the examples and extensive documentation here:
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/

Also while I can understand the urge to jump right in and automate things, you'll have a much easier time if you get it working in the desktop UI first. Then automate it.

If you're **only** seeing the methods you listed then it seems you have v0.17 of the python API package (or well at least not the latest 0.0.18 version that corresponds with Zap 2.10) .

```
user@host:~$ pip install -Iv python-owasp-zap-v2.4==0.0.17 --quiet
user@host:~$ pip show python-owasp-zap-v2.4|grep Version && python3 ./test.py
Version: 0.0.17
['get_authentication_credentials', 'get_authentication_credentials_config_params', 
'get_user_by_id', 'new_user', 'remove_user', 
'set_authentication_credentials', 'set_user_enabled', 'set_user_name', 'users_list', 'zap']
user@host:~$ pip uninstall python-owasp-zap-v2.4
...
user@host:~$ pip install python-owasp-zap-v2.4 --quiet
user@host:~$ pip show python-owasp-zap-v2.4|grep Version && python3 ./test.py
Version: 0.0.18
['authenticate_as_user', 'get_authentication_credentials', 
'get_authentication_credentials_config_params', 'get_authentication_session', 
'get_authentication_state', 'get_user_by_id', 'new_user', 'poll_as_user', 
'remove_user', 'set_authentication_credentials', 'set_authentication_state', 'set_cookie', 
'set_user_enabled', 'set_user_name', 'users_list', 'zap']
```

So while you stated `When I run pip install python-owasp-zap-v2.4 I get: Requirement already satisfied.` That simply means the package is installed, not necessarily latest because you didn't ask pip to upgrade it.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

> Note that `pip install` prefers to leave the installed version as-is unless `--upgrade` is specified.

Comment: Expecting the code to do what the documentation says is expecting too much?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Yes the code is commented as you've outlined, unfortunately it seem the package you're using is older than the code you linked. Code comments/docs should not necessarily be treated as user/usage docs.